# Problems with serial communication from Arduino to ESP8266

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, esp8266, softwareserial

I've been trying to get an Arduino and ESP8266 to communicate with each other over serial. The ESP8266 uses the `Serial` class for communications, while the Arduino uses `SoftwareSerial`.

The problem is that when I try to send data from the Arduino to the ESP8266,  only the first character of the string sent gets received by the ESP8266. For example, if I send a string "leather", the ESP8266 only receives an 'l'. Both devices are operating at 38400 baud, although I have tried 9600 baud with similar results (apparently `SoftwareSerial` is more reliable at lower baud rates).

Here is the relevant code that's running on both devices:

Arduino code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define COMMAND_TILT                'c'
#define SOFTWARE_SERIAL_BAUD_RATE   38400
#define ESP_RX                      8
#define ESP_TX                      9

SoftwareSerial esp(ESP_RX, ESP_TX);

void setup()
{
    ...
    esp.begin(SOFTWARE_SERIAL_BAUD_RATE);
    ...
}

void loop()
{
   if (esp.available() > 0) {
        String data;
        while (esp.available() > 0) {
            data += (char) esp.read();
        }

        char command = data.charAt(0);
        data.remove(0, 1);
        int value = data.toInt();
        char buf[STR_BUF_LEN];

        switch (command) {
             case COMMAND_TILT:
                 ...
                 sprintf(buf, "%c%d", COMMAND_TILT, value);
                 esp.write(buf);
                 break;
             ...
        }
    }

    delay(100);
}

...
```

ESP8266 code:

```
#define SERIAL_BAUD_RATE 38400

void setup()
{
    ...
    Serial.begin(SERIAL_BAUD_RATE);
    ...
}

void loop()
{
    ...

    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
        String data;
        while (Serial.available() > 0) {
            data += (char) Serial.read();
        }

        char command = data.charAt(0);
        data.remove(0, 1);

        // problem: now, data.c_str() is blank when it should contain an integer in string format

        ...

        delay(100);
    }
}

...
```

If it helps to know, I'm running an MQTT client on the ESP8266 and controlling some steppers and relays on the Arduino.

Comment: use SoftwareSerial at 9600 baud. not more

Comment: @Juraj if you read the bottom of my questions it says I tried 9600 baud. Unfortunately no difference.

Comment: why do you thing that data will be available without a gap?

Comment: Strangely I am able to send data from the ESP to the Arduino in two separate `write()` calls and still get it in one piece on the Arduino side. But even if I send the data in one buffer the other way around, the ESP only gets the first character. For any gaps in data, shouldn't the `Serial.available()` calls take care of things? Or do you mean something else entirely?

Comment: `Serial.available()` returns the count of bytes in RX buffer. but at 9600 baud the bytes are coming very slow

Comment: you can use the blocking functions readString or readBytes, but it would be better to know the terminator char. https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the issue was that the ESP was reading `char`s too quickly, meaning that it would give up before the next `char` could be sent from the Arduino. To fix the issue I simply added a 10 ms delay between each `Serial.read()` call on the ESP.